# Why Jotai makes a component infinitely re-render when i define the related atom as a function with parameter?

Tags: reactjs, jotai

i'm trying to implement language state on my website with Jotai and React.

I tried to do something and it worked but the problem is that the the React component started to re-render infinitely.

Here is what i did :

This is a separate file i created for defining atoms,

```
import { atom } from "jotai";

export const languageState = atom('tr')

export const marineHeaderObject = (langState) => atom({
        buttonDataArray: [
            { label: langState === 'tr' ? 'Anasayfa' : 'Home ', path: 'home', isDropdown: false },
            { label: langState === 'tr' ? 'Kurumsal' : 'Corporate ' , path: '', isDropdown: false},
            { label: langState === 'tr' ? 'Modellerimiz' : 'Models ', path: '', isDropdown: true},
            { label: langState === 'tr' ? 'Tekne Kiralama' : 'Boat Rental ', path: '', isDropdown: false},
            { label: langState === 'tr' ? 'Güverte Kaplama' : 'Deck Covering ', path: '', isDropdown: false},
            { label: langState === 'tr' ? 'İletişim' : 'Contact ', path: 'contact', isDropdown: false},
        ],
        logoPath: ''
    }
)
```

This is where i use those atoms,

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useAtom } from 'jotai'

import Header from '../../components/Header';
import { marineHeaderObject } from '../../states';
import { languageState } from '../../states';

const myPage = () => {

    const [langState] = useAtom(languageState)
    const [marineHeader] = useAtom(marineHeaderObject(langState))

    return (
        <div className="pageWrapper">
            <Header headerObject={marineHeader} />
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default myPage;
```

And this is the Header component below,

```
import NavButton from './NavButton'

const Header = ({ headerObject }) => {
    return (
        <div className="header">
            <div className="logo">
                <a> <img height="70" width="184" src="../assets/images/logov2.svg" /> </a>
            </div>
            <div className="navigationBar">
                <nav>
                    {
                        headerObject.buttonDataArray.map((button, index) => {
                            return (
                                <NavButton key={index} buttonData={button} />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Header;
```

And this is what browser console gives me :

```
270react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    at Maycotex (http://localhost:3000/main.9f8185fe9033d1ee3856.hot-update.js:36:69)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41590:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41523:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40332:5)
    at App
```

What's the problem here ? Why React re-renders the component infinitely ?

Comment: I'm facing the same thing, and dunno why

Answer (score 0):

atom() should not be called within a functional component. Place it outside of your functional component.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer to improve it for other readers? Perhaps a link to part of the relevant documentation supporting the answer

Answer (score 0):

`marineHeaderObject` is a function that creates an atom, so if you call it in in `myPage` like so:

```js
const myPage = () => {

    const [langState] = useAtom(languageState)
    const [marineHeader] = useAtom(marineHeaderObject(langState))

    return (
        <div className="pageWrapper">
            <Header headerObject={marineHeader} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

You are creating it inside the component. Which you should **not** do.

Instead you should be doing something like this:

```js
const myPage = () => {

    const [langState] = useAtom(languageState)
    const marineHeaderAtom = useMemo(() => marineHeaderObject(langState), [langState])
    const [marineHeader] = useAtom(marineHeaderAtom)

    return (
        <div className="pageWrapper">
            <Header headerObject={marineHeader} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

The documentation talks about the infinite loop:

> **Note:** as mentioned in the atom section, you have to take care of handling the reference of your atom, otherwise it may enter an
> infinite loop
>
> ```js
> const stableAtom = atom(0)
> const Component = () => {
>   const [atomValue] = useAtom(atom(0)) // This will cause an infinite loop
>   const [atomValue] = useAtom(stableAtom) // This is fine
>   const [derivedAtomValue] = useAtom(
>     useMemo(
>       // This is also fine
>       () => atom((get) => get(stableAtom) * 2),
>       []
>     )
>   )
> }
> ```

Check it out [here](https://jotai.org/docs/core/use-atom#useatom).

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Atom configs can be created anywhere, but referential equality is important. They can be created dynamically too. To create an atom in render function, useMemo or useRef is required to get a stable reference. If in doubt about using useMemo or useRef for memoization, use useMemo. Otherwise, it can cause **infinite loop** with useAtom.

So either declare it separately i.e. outside function component or use below code.

```
const Component = ({ value }) => {
  const valueAtom = useMemo(() => atom({ value }), [value])
  // ...
}
```

Docs link: https://jotai.org/docs/core/atom